# javascript | String replace using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a class string: `width-100 required validate-email validate-unique-email input-success`
And would like to find (special formatted) substring.
Result should be: `validate-email validate-unique-email`

My code:

```
var ok = "width-100 required validate-email validate-unique-email input-success".replace(/validate-([A-Z]+)/gi, function(match, $1, $2) {
   return $1;
});

console.log(ok);
```

But this doesn't work. Where is a mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, you don't actually need to replace, this is why I used `String.prototype.match` instead

```
var str = "width-100 required validate-email validate-unique-email input-success";

console.log(str.match(/\bvalidate-([a-z]+)/gi).join(' '));
```

Comment: If you're ignoring the case at the end, then why is it necessary to use [A-Z]+, wouldn't [a-z]+ be enough?

Comment: I indeed could have changed it earlier, but the string editting problem told me it had the same cost :p

Comment: @mario23 Sorry for having rejected your edit, but `"validate"` seems to be also a possible varying case string in OP's intent

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookahead here,

```
/\bvalidate-([A-Z-]+)(?= |$)/gi
```

Example:

```
> var str = "width-100 required validate-email validate-unique-email input-success";
undefined
> console.log(str.match(/\bvalidate-([A-Z-]+)(?= |$)/gi).join(' '));
validate-email validate-unique-email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\bvalidate-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\b
```

Try this.This will catch word matches.

http://regex101.com/r/kO7lO2/2

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

#### Code

```
var ok=[];
var str = 'width-100 required validate-email validate-unique-email input-success';

str.replace(/(\bvalidate-\w+\b)/gi, function(match) {
   ok.push(match);
});

console.log(ok);
```

#### Output

```
['validate-email', 'validate-unique']
```

#### Note

In this case `replace` is used only to iterate through the matches, and not really for replacing actual bits of `str`.